# get method from content of JInternalframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jinternalframe

I've got MyJPanel(extends JPanel). Each MyJPanel object has method GetID(). When I create it I set ID with constructor(but also there is method SetID()), set size and then create Jscrollpane and add it to JInternalFrame. All frames are in `ArrayList<JInternalFrame> arr`.

```
JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("Inner frame",true,true,true,true);
final MyJPanel panel = new MyJPanel(f.getAbsolutePath(),count);
panel.setSize(panel.getWidth()/6,panel.getHeight()/6);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(theDesktop.getWidth() / 2, theDesktop.getHeight() / 2));
frame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

To delete frame I add add FrameListener and method internalFrameClosing method

```
public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
       int index = panel.GetID();//get index of panel окна
       if (index == arr.size())
          arr.remove(index);//remove last element
       else{
          //reset all indexes of JInternalFrames' MyJPanel
       }
}
```

But I don't know how to reset values for MyJPanels in array of JInternalFrames when one of the frames was deleted because
1)MyJPanel is in JScrollPane. method SetID
2)JScrollPane is in JInternalFrame
3)JInternalFrame is in the array. No method SetID() in `arr.get(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to have a Map such as a HashMap -- `HashMap<JInternalFrame, MyJPanel>` -- that would allow you to easily associated the MyJPanel with the internal frame that holds it. Then when you iterate through the JInternalFrames, it would be easy to retrieve the MyJPanels that each hold.

Something like:

```
public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
  int index = panel.GetID();
  arr.remove(index);
  if (index < arr.size()) {
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        JInternalFrame internalFrame = arr.get(i);
        MyJPanel myPanel = framePanelMap.get(internalFrame);
        myPanel.setID(i);
     }
  }
}
```

Incidentally, you do know that this `if (index == arr.size())` will never be true, since if your index is an index into the list, then index will hold a value between 0 and `arr.size() - 1` and will never == `arr.size()`.

Though this is somewhat of a kludge. In my mind a better solution is perhaps to do a code re-design and have the model logic of your code separate from the view portion of the code so that you would have an ArrayList of models rather than JInternalFrames.

This way, if later you decide that you don't really want to use JInternalFrames to display this information, you wouldn't have to change the basic logical structure of the model.